# Edit text iteratively within a file using commands

Tags: command-line, sed, text-processing

I am a new Ubuntu user. Please help me in solving the following problem:

My input text file is

```
    -0.716425 -12.8939 -3.3341 -7.38497 -2.62709 3.00437
    -6.69861 -13.8853 -5.81095 -7.37465 -0.268193 -5.45344
```

My output text file should look like

```
    1:-0.716425 2:-12.8939 3:-3.3341 4:-7.38497 5:-2.62709 6:3.00437
    7:-6.69861 8:-13.8853 9:-5.81095 10:-7.37465 11:-0.268193
```

I tried `sed` command but didn't get the required results.

How should I do that from command line?

Comment: Your desired output is missing the last number, -5.45344.

Comment: Oh!! sorry .. Yeah it should be 11: -0.268193 12:-5.45344.. Thanks @John1024 for pointing it out.

Comment: @YUVRAJ Do you want to preserve the whitespace as it exists before, between, and after the entries, or may/should it be removed? As written, your input text and desired output text both have four leading spaces at the beginning of each line. But [you've commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608486/edit-text-recursively-within-a-file-using-commands#comment853104_608493) that [John1024's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/608493/22949), which [will *not* preserve the whitespace](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10811761/), gives the correct output. You may wish to [edit] your question to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
-0.716425 -12.8939 -3.3341 -7.38497 -2.62709 3.00437
-6.69861 -13.8853 -5.81095 -7.37465 -0.268193 -5.45344
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s:%s%s",++n,$i,OFS;print""}' file
1:-0.716425 2:-12.8939 3:-3.3341 4:-7.38497 5:-2.62709 6:3.00437 
7:-6.69861 8:-13.8853 9:-5.81095 10:-7.37465 11:-0.268193 12:-5.45344
```

#### How it works

- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s:%s%s",++n,$i,OFS`

  This loops over each field on a line and prints it out with a number prepended.  The variable `n` is the number.  `++n` increments `n` by one each time it is invoked.
- `print""`

  This prints a newline at the end of each line.

#### To update the file in place

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s:%s%s",++n,$i,OFS;print""}' file >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Or, with the [newest versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace/16529730#16529730) of GNU awk (4.1.0+, [in Ubuntu 14.10+](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gawk)):

```
gawk -i inplace '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s:%s%s",++n,$i,OFS;print""}' file
```

Comment: It is displaying output correctly but I want to write the output to same file. So, is it possible??

Comment: @YUVRAJ That is simple enough.  See updated answer for how to update in place.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks.  Answer updated for Ubuntu 14.10+.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU awk (gawk) you can accomplish this with clever record splitting:

```
awk '{ORS=RT; print NR":"$0}' RS='[ \n]+' infile
```

Output:

```
1:-0.716425 2:-12.8939 3:-3.3341 4:-7.38497 5:-2.62709 6:3.00437
7:-6.69861 8:-13.8853 9:-5.81095 10:-7.37465 11:-0.268193 12:-5.45344
```

Comment: How can I write this output to the same file?? It is displaying the output correctly but I want to overwrite it on the same file..

Comment: Is there a way to make this work [even when the input has leading whitespace](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10812086/)?

Comment: @YUVRAJ: write it to a temporary file and overwrite the original after, as suggested by John1024.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Yes, but it is not pretty, besides according to the OPs comment, it seems the white-space is there due to a formatting error. Anyway, if you really wanted to accommodate white-space at the beginning, something like this would work: `file=infile; paste -d '' <(sed -r 's/^(\s*).*/\1/' $file) <(sed -r 's/^\s*//' $file | awk '{ORS=RT; print NR":"$0}' RS='[ \n]+')`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    prev = 0
    for line in f:
        elements = line.rstrip().split()
        for i in range(len(elements)):
            print str(prev + i + 1) + ':' + elements[i],
        print '\n'.rstrip()
        prev = len(elements)
```

**Output:**

```
1:-0.716425 2:-12.8939 3:-3.3341 4:-7.38497 5:-2.62709 6:3.00437 
7:-6.69861 8:-13.8853 9:-5.81095 10:-7.37465 11:-0.268193 12:-5.45344
```

If you want to save the output to the same file, you should save the output to a temporary file first, then remove the original file and then rename the temp file to original file.